# how to prove the monotonicity of this probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Define the following probability as a function of $x>0$:

$$f(x) = \Pr\{T_0 \leq \max\{T_1,T_2,\ldots, T_N\}\},$$

where

1. $T_0$ is a non-central chi-square random variable with DoF${}= 2$ and noncentral parameter $ax$;
2. $T_1,T_2,\ldots, T_N$ are i.i.d. non-central chi-square random variables with DoF${}= 2$ and noncentral parameter $bx$;
3. $a > b >0$.

Question: How to prove that $f(x)$ is monotonically decreasing with respect to $x$?

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: It might be helpful to interpret the non-central chi-squared random variables as the square norms of bivariate Gaussian random variables

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this, but still cannot get around the difficulty from the maximum of a few independent  non-central chi-square rvs. Not sure if other techniques, such as stochastic coupling, would help.